# How to toggle DropdownMenu when clicking a button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this **DropdownMenu** component that works just fine. Basically, if you click on **"Click me"** button you'll see a DropdownMenu then if you either click **outside** the DropdownMenu or **select an option** by clicking on it the Dropdown disappears and this is expected.

My issue is that I want to be able to toggle the Dropdown Menu **when clicking on "Click me"** button, as of right now if I click on "Click me" button the menu shows up, then if I click again on "Click me" button the DropdownMenu won't go away (I want to toggle it). Can anyone point me in the right direction and tell me what I'm missing or need to do please? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's a [**LIVE DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-flower-qon9ou?file=/DropdownMenu.tsx) of my code, and here are the 2 functions that handle the **toggle** for my DropdownMenu and handle the **ClickOutside**.

```
const handleToggle = () => setOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen);

const handleClickOutside = (evt: MouseEvent) =>
  !menuListRef?.current?.contains(evt.target as HTMLElement) &&
   setOpen(false);
```

Comment: Your problem is that when the dropdown is open and you click the button again you are actually triggering the "click outside" event, and then immediately the button again (I can even see the dropdown flicker in my browser). If you add console.log() with info to each finction you will clearly see what is happening.

Comment: @JakubRusilko yup I know exactly what causes the issue, but any ideas how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Add a ref to the button and don't trigger the clickOutside function, if the button is the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a `ref` also on your button:

```
const buttonRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

...

<StyledMenuButton onClick={handleToggle} ref={buttonRef}>
```

And add a check for it not to be the clicked element in `handleClickOutside`:

```
const handleClickOutside = (evt: MouseEvent) => {
  if (!menuListRef?.current?.contains(evt.target as HTMLElement) &&
  !buttonRef?.current?.contains(evt.target as HTMLElement)) {
    setOpen(false);
  }
}
```

[Working](https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-turing-jrmx1c?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
const buttonRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
.
.
.
const handleClickOutside = (evt: MouseEvent) => {
  const dropdownClicked = menuListRef?.current?.contains(
    evt.target as HTMLElement
  );
  const buttonToOpenClicked = buttonRef?.current?.contains(
    evt.target as HTMLElement
  );
  // If nether the button or dropdown menu has been clicked
  // You haven't clicked "outside"
  if (!dropdownClicked && !buttonToOpenClicked) {
    console.log("Clicked outside");
    setOpen(false);
  }
};
.
.
.
<StyledMenuButton onClick={handleToggle} ref={buttonRef}>
```